# trying to insert php variable in onclick in order to set the hidden variable

Tags: javascript, php

Below is the small code having some syntax error in Javascript. iam trying to insert php variable in onclick in order to set the hidden variable ie., $xyz

Iam not getting value for my hidden varible ie., abc

Please tell me what wen wrong inside print.

**here is:**

```
 <form action="/go" method=post>

   <input type=hidden name='abc' >

<?php

            if(someCondition) {
           print "<input type=\"submit\" value=\"My Button\" onclick=\" document.getElementsByName('abc').value = \'<?php echo $xyz ?>\' \" />"; //where $xyz having some value in it.
        } 
?>

</form>
```

**Edit:**
It was type mistake before, now I edited as 'getElementsByName', even then iam still not getting value for my hidden variable ie., abc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. JavaScript is case sensitive, `getelementsbyname` should be `getElementsByName`.
2. This `getElementsByName` function returns a collection, so you can't do the `.value` assignment on the return value.
3. You have a `<?php ?>` tag inside a `<?php ?>` tag.

**Edit:** Here is the code that should work:

```
<form action="/go" method="post">
   <input type="hidden" name="abc">

   <?php
      if (someCondition) {
        echo '<input type="submit" value="My Button" onclick="document.getElementsByName(\'abc\')[0].value = \''.$xyz.'\'" />';
      } 
    ?>
</form>
```

Comment: hey sory, it was typo mistake, now i edited it. but still iam not getting value for my hidden variable 'abc'

Comment: Change `\'<?php echo $xyz ?>\'` to `\'".$xyz."\'`.

Comment: i tried as above , but still not getting value for my hidden variable ie., abc. your sure that your syntax is correct, right?

Comment: @user3815806 This `method=post` and `type=hidden` is missing quotes. Plus, you need to define your named POST variable. Using [**error reporting**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php), would have signaled that.

Comment: @user3815806 As I wrote, your code had multiple issues. Added the code to my answer that should work.

Comment: Thanks a lot bro! you made my day! :) i given tick mark for you..